# Which Group 16 elements form stable dihalides?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, halides, stability, halogens, oxygen

My textbook says that "except oxygen, all elements of group 16 form dichlorides and dibromides", while other sources quote that only Oxygen and Sulphur form dihalides and dibromides.
Whereas, +2 Oxidation state being less stable for elements down the group, they should not be forming dihalides. So, I am unable to find concrete reason to support any of these claims, and want to ascertain which all chalcogens can actually form dihalides?

Comment: Why not to review chemistry of particular chalkogens? You would then see if a particular element forms them or not.

Answer (score 3):

> except oxygen, all elements of group 16 form dichlorides and dibromides

That's true because $\ce{Cl2O}$ and $\ce{Br2O}$ are not halides but rather oxides of chlorine and bromine respectively. Oxygen is more electronegative than chlorine and bromine so the compounds are oxide rather than halides.

All other group 16 elements form dichlorides and dibromides as expected.

Comment: It's not so simple, for example TeCl2 disproportionates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritellurium_dichloride

Comment: @Mithoron If it disproportions, it must exist in the first place, doesn't it? ;)